# Why can we have $\{Y\leq k\}=\bigcup^{k+1}_{i=1}\{X_i=1\}$?

Tags: probability

Let $X_n\sim^{iid} Ber(p)$, and $Y:=\inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}: X_n =1\}-1$.

Then, why can we have $\{Y\leq k\}=\bigcup^{k+1}_{i=1}\{X_i=1\}$?

I think that $\{Y\leq k\}=\underbrace{\{X_1=1\}\cup \{X_1=0 \land X_2=1\}}_{=\{X_1=1\}\cup \{X_2=1\}}\cup...\cup \{X_1=0\land ... \land X_k=0\land X_{k+1}=1\}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct, but so is the given formula. Note that the union is not claimed to be disjoint.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, but as Hagen von Eitzen commented, the union need not be of disjoint sets, and the given form is equivalent.

Notice that $\{(X_1=1)\vee(X_1=0 \wedge X_2=1)\} = \{X_1=1\vee X_2=1\}$, and so on.

So then $\{X_1=1\}\cup\{X_1=0 \wedge X_2=1\}\cup\cdots\{\bigwedge_{n=1}^k (X_n=0)\wedge(X_{k+1}=1)\} \\= \{X_1=1\}\cup\{X_2=1\}\cup\{X_3=1\}\cup\cdots\cup\{X_{k+1}=1\}$